# Image Uploaded From PowerApp Is Not Viewable

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, powerapp, image

I have created a very simple Power App that takes a picture on the phone, then uploads it to a SharePoint Library, using a flow.  The actual upload works, but when the picture arrives in SharePoint, it is not viewable.  By that I mean when you click on it, you cannot preview it, and if you download it, Image Viewer says that the file format is not supported.  Here is the code that does the actual upload:

```
UploadKittyPic.Run(
txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text,
{
    contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
    name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss.jpg")
}
);
```

Here is my flow:

[image]

Just changing the file extension has no effect, and I can't de-compress the file.  This is so close to being a solution I need, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the image file extension in **File Name** property of **Create file** action in Power automate.

Try adding `.png` after `image_utcNow()` in **Create file** action like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Check this: http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2017/06/27/a-filename-generation-example-for-powerapps-with-flow/. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Maaaaan, that is a lot of work just to upload a photo!!!!  Thanks for the pointer, it's going to take me quite a while to work through that though.

Comment: You don't need to follow everything. Just check how to get the file name with extension in power automate from power apps.

Comment: Or try this: Use formula in Power apps like: `UploadKittyPic.Run(
 txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text,
 {
  contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
  name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss") & ".jpg"
 }
);` Then change the "File Name" property in flow to get the `name` from inputs passed from power apps. You will have to use the expression something like in this format: `triggerBody()['file']['name']`

Comment: So, no further forward unfortunately.  That blog appears to be a little out of date as I had to change the instructions slightly, but when I get to the end of it, the flow fails stating it is expecting an array, but what it got was a string in the apply to each section.  I will keep plugging away and post an answer when I have one.